# Python_Django - Adding Attending Event option - How to?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

There are 3 models in my web application. Event (self-made), User (imported from django.contrib.auth.models) and EventAttendance (self-made).
EventAttendance is a table which connects Event and User table (through foreign keys person_key and event_key).

I would like to create a button which will connect the user (the one who is logged in) and the Event. It should insert a line into the table EventAttendance.
I was trying to make it work but unfortunatelly it is not doing anything. Right now i am able to put data into EventAttendance table just through the ADMIN tab.

Could somebody please check my code and give me some advices?

**MODELS**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    place = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class EventAttendance(models.Model):
    person_key = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event_key = models.ForeignKey('Event', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attended = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.event_key, self.person_key)
```

**FORMS**`

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Event
    fields = ('title', 'text','place','start','price',)

class EventAttendanceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = EventAttendance
    widgets = {
        'event_key': forms.HiddenInput(),
    }
    fields = ['person_key', 'event_key', 'attended',]

class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ( "username", "email" )
```

**VIEW**

```
def event_attendance(request,pk):
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=pk)
    #if request.method == "POST":
    form = EventAttendanceForm(request.POST)
    EventAttendance = form.save(commit=False)
    EventAttendance.person_key = user.id
    EventAttendance.event_key = event.id
    EventAttendance.attended = 1
    EventAttendance.save()
    return redirect('event_detail', pk=event.pk)

    return render(request, 'events/post_detail.html', )

 def event_new(request):
     if request.method == "POST":
        form = EventForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           event = form.save(commit=False)
           event.author = request.user
           event.published_date = timezone.now()
           event.save()
           return redirect('event_detail', pk=event.pk)
     else:
          form = EventForm()
     return render(request, 'events/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

**TEMPLATE** - where i use it

```
{% extends 'events/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="event">
    {% if event.published_date %}
        <div class="date">
          <p> <u>Pridane:</u> {{ event.published_date }} </p>
          <p> </p>
          <p> <u>Autor:</u> {{ event.author }} </p>

          <br>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'event_edit' pk=event.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'event_remove' pk=event.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'event_attendance' pk=event.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></a>
    <h1>{{ event.title }}</h1>
    <p><u>Miesto</u>: {{ event.place }} </p>
    <p><u>Zaciatok</u>: {{ event.start }} </p>
    <p><u>Cena</u>: {{ event.price }} </p>
    <br>

    <p><u>Zucastneni:</u> {{attendance}}</p>
    <br>
    <p><u>Blizsie Informacie:</u></p>
    <p>{{ event.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**base.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<html>
  <head>
      <title>Eventovy katalog</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/events.css' %}">
   </head>
     <body>
        <div class="page-header">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <a href="{% url 'event_new' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
        {% endif %}
        <h1><a href="/">Eventovy katalog</a></h1>
         </div>
        <div class="content container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                {% block content %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**post_edit.html**

```
{% extends 'events/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
   <h1>Pridaj event</h1>
   <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
   </form>
{% endblock %}
```

If you need any additional details just pls let me know and ill upload them somewhere.

Thank you for your time!

This is my new function but i am still struggling with inserting new rows into my DB. Any suggestions?

```
def event_attendance(request):
    event = get_object_or_404(Event)
    attendance = EventAttendance(person_key = request.user , 
    event_key = event.id, attended = True)
    attendance.save(force_insert=True)
    transaction.commit()
    return render(request, 'events/post_detail.html')
```

Comment: are you getting the values from post? where is your form displayed? have you tried printing request.POST

Comment: @Exprator  - I tried to print it and this is what i get   <QueryDict: {}>   ... So it looks like it is not working.

Comment: yes your query is not returning anything, you need to change the query

Comment: Right now i am a little bit lost. I tried to do it that way but nothing is happening inside of the DB (no new instance created):  I edited my post and you can see there my new function.

Comment: you are trying to enter the event for an user to the eventattendance table right? the user logs in and selects and event and then submit the form? this will enter the value right?

Comment: have posted an answer use it. hope it will solve your errot

Comment: go to cmd and type python manage.py shell, import the eventattendance model and type and check whether this inserts value inthe table EventAttendance.objects.create(person_key=1,event_key=1,attended = True)

Comment: Could you be more specific of how to do that please? What to write in the shell? I tried `EventAttendance.objects.create(person_key=1,event_key=1,atte‌​nded = True)`  and `import EventAttendance` but both came out with an error.  `NameError: name 'EventAttendance' is not defined`

Comment: from appname.models import EventAttendance then run the query

Comment: OK I did it. First when i tried it with the code mentioned above i got this error  `Cannot assign "1": "EventAttendance.person_key" must be a "User" instance.`. I tried to set person_key = NAME (username from the DB) but got following: error `Cannot assign "'Pavol'": "EventAttendance.person_key" must be a "User" instance. ` ... After that i changed i a little bit more and it worked. This is what i used: `EventAttendance.objects.create(person_key_id=1,event_key_id=8,attended = True)` ... Could we use it somehow inside of the function in view?

Comment: @Exprator  Any suggestions left that i could try to implemet please ? :-)

Comment: added one answer, give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was in my urls.py file:

Previous value:

```
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.event_attendance, name='event_attendance')
```

New value:

```
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/attendance/$', views.event_attendance, name='event_attendance')
```

Maybe it is going to server someone in the future!